# I need to draw GLines from the values from my random array

Tags: java, arrays, graphics

Create a java program that creates a random integer array and draws GLine shapes by using
values of the array. You should have two methods; one for creating a random array which
has length values of lines and one for drawing lines. If current index of the array is even the
line will be drawn in x-axis with the length value of current index, otherwise it will be drawn in
y-axis with the length value of current index. For example; for index 0, line will be drawn in
x-axis (horizontal) and for index 1, it will be drawn in y-axis (vertical)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import acm.graphics.GLine;
import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;
import acm.util.RandomGenerator;

public class project extends GraphicsProgram{


private RandomGenerator rgen = new RandomGenerator();
public void run(){

    int n = readInt("Enter n");
    int[]intArray=new int[n];
    int min= readInt("enter min");
    int max= readInt("enter max");
    for(int i = 0;i< intArray.length;i++){
        intArray[i]=rgen.nextInt(min,max);
    }
}
}
```

I got this far and don't know what to do next please help.

Comment: How about create the method signatures next for the two methods you need? And move your array creation code into a separate method, like the directions state

Comment: @forgivenson touched on a good tool for your programmer's toolbox. When programming from scratch, think at a higher level of what steps need to be done to accomplish your full software and define these steps into simple methods. 

These can be tasks like "Create random array", "Draw Lines from Array". Once you have these larger tasks, break them into smaller tasks, if need be, like "Draw a single vertical line" and "Draw a single horizontal line". By continuing this path of thinking you can break down complex problems into simple steps, which allows for easier programming.